# 2048 - How do I stop my tiles from merging twice?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a merging algorithm and it works fine except for one thing: a single tile can merge twice in one move so 4224 becomes 8400 instead of 4440 when I move left. 
I've tried adding a break statement at the end of the else if block and adding a flag if a tile has merged but none of these things helped. I sincerely apologise for any mistakes that I might have made but this is my first post on stackoverflow.

```
#define TILES_X 4
#define TILES_Y 4
//Moving UP with SDL library
for (int i = 0; i < TILES_X; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < TILES_Y; j++) {
        if (gameBoard[i][j] != 0) {
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                if (gameBoard[i][k] == 0) {
                    gameBoard[i][k] = gameBoard[i][j];
                    gameBoard[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else if (gameBoard[i][k] == gameBoard[i][j] && (gameBoard[i][k+1]==0||gameBoard[i][k+1]==gameBoard[i][k])) {
                    gameBoard[i][k] = 2 * gameBoard[i][j];
                    gameBoard[i][j] = 0;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't modify the game board in-place. Make a new one and populate it with the new state.